# Replicate CKAN instance (installation from source) to another server

Tags: python, postgresql, ckan

**Problem:** I would like to replicate a CKAN instance which has been installed from source to another server. The aim is that the new server will be used for staging any updates developed into the development server (CKAN is already installed there) and will be pushed to the productions server to update any functionality. I couldn't find any guidelines in the CKAN documentation on how to achieve the replication although there is extensive documentation on migrating to newer CKAN versions.

**Background:** Ubuntu 14.04, CKAN 2.5.2b, PostgreSQL 9.4.6. I have customized some of the python functions which I would also like to preserve.

Any documentation, experiences, or workflows would be more than welcome.

Comment: Usually your code modification should only be in extension packages. Why not simply use git for syncing those packages?

Comment: Hi Hendrik, I am not familiar with git syncing. Is there any reviewed documentation that you would suggest? I had to go into the python code because at the time we integrated CKAN with WordPress and we had a complex authentication system. I understand that extending CKAN using plugins makes more sense.

Comment: There is a plethora of git documentation and tutorials on the web. Start with the official docs at https://git-scm.com/documentation. If you followed the official CKAN documentation for source installs you should already have the git repository. Make your own branch and modify the code as needed. You can then easily push this branch (and any later modifications) to the CKAN repo on your production server.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check this [Ansible playbook](https://github.com/govro/datagovro/blob/master/provisioning/playbook.yml) that sets up a new installation from source. It's based on the original docs.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for this resource. Will take a look although from a preliminary look I can see it is a sequence of actions for installing CKAN from source. My goal is to replicate the existing CKAN installation in our production system and copy it across to another host.